# Starting Hbase : cygpath: can't convert empty path

Tags: cygwin, hbase

I hope somebody can help me with this problemoo:

Starting hbase, I get this error:

```
$ ./start-hbase.sh
cygpath: can't convert empty path
cygpath: can't convert empty path
soporte@localhost's password:
localhost: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/local/hbase-0.90.4/bin/../logs/hbase-CNEOSYLAP-zookeeper-CNEOSYLAP.out
localhost: cygpath: can't convert empty path
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase-0.90.4/bin/../logs/hbase-CNEOSYLAP-master-CNEOSYLAP.out
cygpath: can't convert empty path
soporte@localhost's password:
localhost: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase-0.90.4/bin/../logs/hbase-CNEOSYLAP-regionserver-CNEOSYLAP.out
localhost: cygpath: can't convert empty path
```

This error only happens with hbase-0.90.4 and hbase-0.90.6 but is not happening with hbase-0.94.9. I am using Windows 7 x64 and CygWin setup 2.774.

Note 1 : I was following instructions from [Installing HBase on Windows](http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290223/hbase-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-classpath-error)
Note 2 : It is important to me setting up hbase-0.90.X because later i will use Nutch 2.2.1

Thanks

Comment: i also followed the instruction in the attached link with  hbase version 2.2.3. i correct all paths and also added JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH, the cygpath issue gone. i got some warning about SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.. the hbase start fails at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps some problem in the conversion of unix style paths into windows style path by cygpath or the path is actually empty. Remember cygpath is a cygwin utility that converts unix style file paths into windows style file paths, and vice versa. I personally don't trust this completely. So, please make sure that you are not facing those kinda issues. For a smooth functioning, I would like to suggest a couple of things though :

- Modify the line **# export HBASE_CLASSPATH=** in **hbase-env.sh** file as per your environment :
  **export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/programs/hbase-0.90.4/lib/**
- The property **hbase.rootdir** in your hbse-site.xml is in terms with your cygwin environment :
  Something like **file:///C:/cygwin/root/tmp/hbase/data**

Somehow I feel that using Hadoop/HBase on windows is always a pain. You can avoid these problems by getting yourself a Linux box(if possible) or make use of some VM.

HTH

P. S. : Is your Hadoop running fine(if you have it)?

**Edit :**

Add these lines in you **hbase** file under **hbase-0.90.4/bin** directory, if not present :

```
# cygwin path translation
if $cygwin; then
  CLASSPATH=`cygpath -p -w "$CLASSPATH"`
  HBASE_HOME=`cygpath -d "$HBASE_HOME"`
  HBASE_LOG_DIR=`cygpath -d "$HBASE_LOG_DIR"`
```

I do not have older releases right now with me so that I can crosscheck.

Comment: I configured hbase-env.sh and hbase-default.xml using cygwin format (As apache tech notes said). I am running hbase in standalone mode, but thanks, I am  really thinking in leave in peace windows and start with linux.

Comment: Same behaviour @Tariq

Comment: Indeed lines existing in hbase

Comment: I note that this error does not affect the correct functionality of Hbase. I means that cygwin is trying to convert an empty path : JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
bin/start-hbase.cmd
```

instead of

```
bin/start-hbase.sh
```