# Running Apache kafka on Windows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to run Kafka in my laptop via cygwin. I set the below parameter as suggested in many links.

```
exec $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp  `cygpath -p -w "$CLASSPATH"` $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"
```

However I see the below error -

```
[/cygdrive/c/CTP/software/kafka-0.11.0.0-src]bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
cygpath: can't convert empty path
```

Please can you let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is may be beacause you are building from the source package on windows. try using the binary package from [here](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/0.11.0.0/kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0.tgz).

Also try creating new directories for logs and zookeeper. The name of the directories should be `kafka-logs` and `zookeeper`. Also see this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887365/starting-hbase-cygpath-cant-convert-empty-path)

Comment: Thanks Tony , I set it and see the below error - [/cygdrive/c/CTP/software/kafka-0.11.0.0-src]bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
cygpath: can't convert empty path
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class config.zookeeper.properties

Comment: just saw in another post it is because I downloaded source package. I will download binary and check